# why i cannot access Mumbai polygon

Tags: wallets, smart-contract-wallets, wagmi

I want to access Mumbai polygon.
I'm using wagmi with this config

```
const { chains } = configureChains(
[polygonMumbai],
[publicProvider()],
```

)

but in provider i see only mainnet [image]

How should i config it to work proverly? before i used this func and it worked fine

```
export const walletConnection = async () => {
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
        provider.provider.url = "https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com";
        await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
        const signer = await provider.getSigner();
        return { provider, signer}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Was faced with a similar issue, quick fixed it using alchemy for mumbai testnet, whilst public provider for other chains.

```
    const { chains, publicClient } = configureChains(
      [mainnet, polygon, optimism, arbitrum, zora, polygonMumbai],
      [alchemyProvider({ apiKey: 'apikey' }), 
      publicProvider()]
    );
```